# Using Google Analytics to Track 'offline' Media?

Tags: google-analytics, usb, tracking, offline

I'm currently working on a project where we've created a single-page website that contains a number of resources and information (including e-mails and external links to departmental sites, etc) -  the site (page) will live on a USB which we will hand out to our customers over the summer.

Naturally, it'd be great to see if this campaign is successful by tracking whether or not folks are opening/using the USB site.  My first thought was to alter all the out-going links to track folks via the Campaigns in Google Analytics; but since we do not own or have access to *all* of the various departments, this isn't an ideal solution.

My next thought was to add click events and track things that way - this would give us a nice snapshot of what folks viewing the USB were doing on it (provided they were connected to the internet at the time - we're not tremendously concerned with the accuracy of the stats, just a jist of usage).  But since the site lives on a physical drive...and you can't set up a tracking account in GA without an address it seems this won't work.

My question is...is there a way around this?  It almost seems like app tracking is a mix of what we need, but without being an actual app.  Anyone have any advice?

Worse case scenario we just go with option 1 - best case scenario someone out there is more brilliant than I.